# How can I achieve this SQL table connection?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database-design

I've been trying to figure out how to create links between different tables and am having no luck at cracking the mystery.  The more I learn the more I question what questions I should be asking.  I made some table diagrams to show what I'm trying to achieve...

I have a shirts table which looks like this:

[image: shirts table]

Notice in the columns labeled "qp_price" and "o_price" I have text instead of prices, that's because I want to connect it to this table:

[image: price list]

The values of the "qp_price" and "o_price" are equal to one of the values in the "price_cat" column in the price table.  This is my way of trying to simplify price management in the future.  In the shirts table you'll see there are repeated values which is because they cost the same price, besides just the men's shirts there will be women's crewnecks, boys, girls and babies.  I want to link them into a new shirts table where it results like this:

[image: master shirts]

I was also wondering about indexes and if it would be better to create this as an index:

[image: shirts index]

then inject it into the shirts_master table however you do it and add the "clr_options" and "qty" columns on to the shirts_master table.  I want it organized with the two different prices because I have two types of custom services that will call to the appropriate column.  In the end I still want the shirts and price tables individual, just linked onto another table so I can update them and have it automatically read it in the master table through the link.  What would be the smartest way to put this together?

Comment: Out of interest why is qp_price and o_price in the Shirts table not linking to Price table via price_id?

Comment: u want copy them to the new table or you just want shirts_master and keep the old table and update them both?

Comment: I tried linking them that way and in the new table I just saw the price_id in the qp_price and o_price slots instead of the price.  Is there a way I can get it to show the price instead of the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you want to do, but you can get your `shirts_master` with a simple join

```
select s.shirt_id, s.shirt_name, s.shirt_type, s.shirt_size,
       qp.price as qp_price, o.price as o_price, s.clr_options, s.qty
from shirts s
join price_list qp on qp.price_cat = s.qp_price
join price_list o on o.price_cat = s.o_price;
```

If you want this as a view, you can create it with

```
create view shirts_master as
select s.shirt_id, s.shirt_name, s.shirt_type, s.shirt_size,
       qp.price as qp_price, o.price as o_price, s.clr_options, s.qty
from shirts s
join price_list qp on qp.price_cat = s.qp_price
join price_list o on o.price_cat = s.o_price;
```

Comment: @user1811846 If the OP wants to update the tables `shirts`, `prices` and `shirts_master` independently. But then you risk getting inconsistencies.

Comment: GREAT THIS WORKED!!!!.... somehow... but how do I get it to where I have two columns with prices like in the shirts_master table? and how can I set the names of those columns in the new table? THANKS!!!!

Comment: incase you're wondering, it just created a price for the qp_prices... but not the o_prices..

Comment: @DaMightyOptiq Sorry, forgot to give `as` names to the two columns. Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

Your columns `qp_price` and `o_price` from SHIRT table should be a **Foreign Key** which references to column `price_id`in table PRICE_LIST. Then you won't need the column `price_cat` in PRICE_LIST table.

Comment: I tried that before, but it was showing the price_id in the columns I want the prices to show up in on the new table.  How can I link the qp_price and o_price to the price_id and get the price to show and not the id?

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to "build" new tables, but `shirt_master` shouldn't exist in your database... You can use a query to retrieve such data: `SELECT s.shirt_id s.shirt_name, s.shirt_type, s.shirt_size, p.price FROM shirts s LEFT JOIN price_list p on p.price_id = s.price_id`.

Comment: let me try to explain it a little better, sorry for not being clear enough.  What I want is to make 1 table for my shirts, then another table for the prices, then I want to make a new table that shows the prices for each shirt.  In the shirts table I have the "qp_price" and "o_price" set the way I do so I can go into my "price_list" table and change one price instead of having to change  ton of them.  For example, one of the values I have set is "crn_qp_a", on my shirts table I have that value set to 25 different shirts,

Comment: so when I change that on the price_list table the change will automatically apply to all 25 shirts linked through that value.  So I guess you could say I want the shirts table in place to set the groundwork and dynamics for how the shirts_master table will work, which is what I'll be linking the rest of my site from, which is why I was curious about if I should just make an index out of the info to store that logic. does this make more sense?

Comment: I understand, but `shirt_master` table is a combination of two tables you already have in your DB, why you need a third table populated with data you already have in other tables?

Comment: Otherwise, I now realise your `price_cat` meaning, but anyway you should use `price_id` to refer price in table `shirts` as a `FOREIGN KEY`.

Comment: 'code'CREATE TABLE shirts(
shirt_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
shirt_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
shirt_type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
shirt_size VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
qp_price NUMERIC(6,2) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES price_list.price ON price_list.price_id=shirts.qp_price NOT NULL,
o_price NUMERIC(6,2) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCE price_list.price ON price_list.price_id=shirts.o_price NOT NULL,
clr_options VARCHAR(30) NULL,
qty NUMERIC(5,0) NULL)ENGINE=INNODB"'code'

Comment: that's the script I came up with so far, but it doesn't work, how can I fix it?

Comment: I suggest you first create the table (without specifying the foreign keys) and then you add the constraints. MySQL syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: `CREATE shirts(
  shirt_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  shirt_type VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL, 
  shirt_size VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  qp_price NUMERIC(6,2) NOT NULL,
  o_price NUMERIC(6,2) NOT NULL,
  clr_options VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  qty NUMERIC(5,0) NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (qp_price) REFERENCES price_list(price_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (o_price) REFERENCES price_list(price_id)
  )engine=INNODB;` That will be your SQL command for create the table you specify. Notice you may need to specify actions for FK's (ON UPDATE | ON DELETE) to ensure DB consistency.